# Meteor - How to get IP address of current visitor in Helper

Tags: meteor

I tried using this approach but I get undefined as the value for the variable named clientIpAddress.

```
Meteor.methods({
    getClientIpAddress: function () {
        return this.connection.clientAddress;
    }
});

Template.home.helpers({
    starsAlreadyReceivedFromIpAddress: function () {
        var clientIpAddress;
        Meteor.call("getClientIpAddress", function(err, ipAddress) {
           clientIpAddress = ipAddress;
        });
        console.log(clientIpAddress);
        ....
    }
});
```

If some one could assist me with this, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `user-status` package.  https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

This gives you `Meteor.user().status.lastLogin.ipAddr` which you can then use in a helper (first make sure the field is published).

Comment: Your answer worked great. Thanks for the really quick and accurate response.

Comment: Actually Jeremy I have a issue though ... that the code does not work unless the user is logged in. I am using accounts-password package. For logged in users I get the ip address, but not for visitors who are not signed in. Could you help me with that ...

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sorry, I wasn't sensitive to the user vs. visitor distinction. In fact the way you are doing it by returning this.connection.clientAddress from the server is correct.  However you should not be calling the method from a helper. Using Meteor.call from a helper is a bad pattern, but in addition, will run asynchronously in your case but won't rerun once the result returns because it is not a reactive data source. Instead, do the call from somewhere else in your code (in a router before action would be a good place) and save the result to a variable you can access in your helper.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a nice solution. I am gonna implement that. Thanks so much for responding to my comment, and giving me a positive direction towards resolving the issue.